# Adding a row to a pandas database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a row to an empty data frame but I'm having issues with adding it with the following code. If anybody could suggest a fix I'd appreciate it.

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
new_row = {'Year':2020,'Jan':1,'Feb':2,'Mar':3,'Apr':4,'May':5,'Jun':6,'Jul':7,'Aug':8,'Sep':9,'Oct':10,'Nov':11,'Dec':12}
df.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Year, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
Index: []
```

Comment: It appended the row. The command to display it, in the interpreter at least, would be the `df` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method does not work in place but returns a new DataFrame, you need to save the output:

```
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

*NB. keep in mind that `append` is slow. It is fine to use once, but if you need to repeatedly append new rows better construct a list an call once the `DataFrame` constructor.*